# imageWithContentsOfFile return nil And imageWithData return nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I want get a image use imageWithContentsOfFile from a path,but it return nil.Then i try imageWithData,it return nil,but the data not nil. Please help me，thank you very much！
The path like "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F865E931-B673-4295-8AC3-B5C3560A10D6/Library/Caches/pic/0513041abff0edbb0e909a1364abe2ed.jpg"
By the way, on the simulator will not appear this kind of circumstance, returns nil case only on the real machine.

```
NSString * strDestinationPath = [[mainKeepData getPicturesPath] stringByAppendingString:imageName];
NSFileManager * fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        BOOL bl1 = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:strDestinationPath];
        if (bl1 == NO)
        {
            [request setDownloadDestinationPath:strDestinationPath];
            [request setCompletionBlock:^(void){
                UIImage * image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:strDestinationPath];
                [PictureDict setValue:image forKey:strGUID];
                [self.delegate DownloadPictureIsOver:YES RequestID:RequetID];
            }];

            [request setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strGUID] forKey:@"name"]];
            [networkQueue addOperation:request];
        }
        else
        {
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:strDestinationPath];
           UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            [PictureDict setValue:image forKey:strGUID];
        }
```

get the path function

```
+(NSString *)getPicturesPath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *cachesDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePath = [cachesDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/pic/"];
    filePath=[filePath stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: how to are getting strDestinationPath ?

Comment: Did you check, whether the data referred by the path *is* a valid jpeg?

Comment: the path and picture is available

Comment: Only a few cases returned nil not all

Comment: may i know in above code what is your requirement ? as per your code i think you are downloading multiple images from server and store in local cache right ?

Comment: To Dhanesh yes,you are right.

Comment: ok so i would suggest here use one of the best 3rd party library to manage every thing with image download store and not download image again.

Comment: @ Dhanesh  thank you,I will consider

Answer (score 0):

Can try this, might be help you

```
NSString *stringPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/pic/"];

return stringPath;

// If you want particular image path
stringPath  = [stringPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Your Img Name"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:stringPath];
```

Happy coding...

Comment: sailendra kumar,thank you. but the image is nil still

Comment: sailendra kumar  yes

Comment: l have use imageWithContentsOfFile/imageWithData,return image not nil most time. But a few pictures of return is nil.

Comment: ok..it's not replicated every time. The image which returns nil, just verify that it's there in the document directory or not (inside your pic)

Comment: I belive it exist. dataWithContentsOfFile return data not nil.And if l use simulator, the image(The same image) will show.

Comment: In real device you are facing problem??

Comment: In stringByAppendingPathComponent:, just pass your image file name, not the whole path. let me know once you verified..

Comment: It donot work if just use image file name. But I find my original code work when celan cache. Do you know why?

Comment: ohh...good. Sometimes the path may be change (means reference to old path), yes clearing the cache, it will work.